# (Shopify) How to render html elements below/above Add To Cart Button (Product Page)?

Tags: javascript, shopify, shopify-app

I am developing a Shopify app that render html elements below/above the add to cart button of the product page. However, I am not sure how to find the exact location of the add to cart button.

The code below is what I am using to find the add to cart button for the Shopify Dawn Theme.

```
document.querySelector('product-form')
```

The problem is this solution may not work for other themes.
Is there any way to make this work across all themes?

Comment: It think you need to provide an option in the app backend settings to add selectors for different locations and buttons. like collection and product page

Comment: There are a number of themes that you can't automate, for all by default, automate it from Shopify published themes, and mentioned in section as a description if the theme is customized or other than Shopify then add a selector into the settings

Comment: Can you talk more about providing an option in the app's backend settings?

Comment: means into app backend settings where the user adds the id or classes of a button from the product page.

Comment: something like this https://prnt.sc/sYQNdGYYiyjz

Answer (score 0):

Each theme is different so you need to either:

- devise an algorithm to try to find the add to cart button. Note that HTML markup and languages on every site will be different
- add an option to input CSS selector by merchant so your JS knows where to append element
- use [Theme App Extensions](https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/online-store/theme-app-extensions) (Recommended)